# Add JS call on Rails form_for submit button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a `form_for` in Rails with a submit button

```
<%= f.submit "Sign up", class: 'login-button w-button', data: {wait: 'Please wait...'} %>
```

and I need to add a Facebook Ads Registration call

```
fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration');
```

How do I do this? Can I add it with `onClick` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `onclick` as an argument to the `submit` helper:

```
<%= f.submit 'Click me', onclick: 'console.log("clicked");' %>
```

You could try with something like:

```
<%= f.submit "Sign up", class: 'login-button w-button', data: { wait: 'Please wait...' }, onclick: 'fbq("track", "CompleteRegistration")' %>
```

Comment: It's not working, it's generating this: `<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign up" class="login-button w-button" data-wait="Please wait...">`

Comment: are you sure? what does the console print?

Comment: can you try at least wih an alert? `<%= form.submit 'Send', class: 'login-button w-button', data: {wait: 'Please wait...'}, onclick: 'alert("bla")' %>`

Comment: I don't see anything in the console either

Comment: the alert must run in the browser, not be printed in the console, as is pure JS it mustn't have problems, can you paste or show how you've tried?

Comment: Glad to help (: